# Performant running SUM OVER Partition in LINQ

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I am trying to figure out the best way to calculate a running sum partition with a self joined collection using LINQ.

The query below is a somewhat simple example of what I am after. The output is the RowNumber, the RowType and the sum of all preceding RowValues within the current row's RowType.

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (RowNumber INT, RowType INT, RowValue INT) 

INSERT @T VALUES (1,1,1),(2,1,1),(3,1,1),(4,1,1),(5,1,1),(6,2,1),(7,2,1),(8,2,1),(9,2,1),(10,2,1) 

;WITH Data AS(SELECT RowNumber, RowType,RowValue FROM @T)

SELECT
    This.RowNumber,
    This.RowType,
    RunningValue = COALESCE(This.RowValue + SUM(Prior.RowValue),This.RowValue)
FROM
    Data This
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Data Prior ON Prior.RowNumber <  This.RowNumber AND Prior.RowType = This.RowType
GROUP BY
    This.RowNumber,
    This.RowType,
    This.RowValue
/* OR
SELECT
    This.RowNumber,
    This.RowType,
    RunningValue = SUM(RowValue) OVER (PARTITION BY RowType ORDER BY RowNUmber)
FROM
    Data This
*/
```

Now, my not working attempt.

```
var joinedWithPreviousSums = allRows.Join(
    allRows,
    previousRows => new {previousRows.RowNumber, previousRows.RowType, previousRows.RowValue}, 
    row=> new { row.RowNumber, row.RowType, row.RowValue}, 
    (previousRows, row) => new { row.RowNumber, row.RowType, row.RowValue })
    .Where(previousRows.RowType == row.RowType && previousRows.RowNumber < row.RowNumber)
    .Select(row.RowNumber, row.RowType,RunningValue = Sum(previousRows.Value) + row.RowValue)).ToList()
```

Of course, the last two lines above are garbage and attempt to exemplify my desired projection while hinting at my lack of knowledge on performant complex LINQ projections.

I have read where some variation of the statement below could work and may be workable, however, is there a way to achieve similar results without yielding?

```
int s = 0;
var subgroup  = people.OrderBy(x => x.Amount)
                      .TakeWhile(x => (s += x.Amount) < 1000)
                      .ToList();
```

EDIT : I have been able to get the snippet below to work, however, I cant seem to partition or project over RowType.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        delegate string CreateGroupingDelegate(int i);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List <TestClass> list = new List<TestClass>() 
               {
                    new TestClass(1, 1, 1),
                    new TestClass(2, 2, 5), 
                    new TestClass(3, 1, 1 ),
                    new TestClass(4, 2, 5),
                    new TestClass(5, 1, 1),
                    new TestClass(6, 2, 5)
            };
            int running_total = 0;

            var result_set = list.Select(x => new { x.RowNumber, x.RowType, running_total = (running_total = running_total + x.RowValue) }).ToList();


            foreach (var v in result_set)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("list element: {0}, total so far: {1}",
                    v.RowNumber,
                    v.running_total);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class TestClass
    {
        public TestClass(int rowNumber, int rowType, int rowValue)
        {
            RowNumber = rowNumber;
            RowType = rowType;
            RowValue = rowValue;
        }

        public int RowNumber { get; set; }
        public int RowType { get; set; }
        public int RowValue { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Comment: Your LINQ isn't close to workable - the `Join` will join each row with itself, it isn't a cross-join. For a proper cross-join, you need to use two parameter `SelectMany`.

Comment: You are correct, allItems.SelectMany(item => allItems.Where(x=>x.RowNumber < item.RowNumber).Select(p=>p) seems to put me on the right path, however, I have to hang a group by and sum somewhere :/

Comment: I find your SQL `GROUP BY` of `This.RowValue` at the end a little puzzling - shouldn't `RowNumber` (per `RowType`) be unique and sufficient?

Comment: Yes, RowValue is not required in the grouping and was a typo on my part to get an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer can be simplified greatly, but does scale poorly even then, as it must go through the `Where` for each row to compute each row, so O(`list.Count^2`).

Here is the simpler version, which preserves the original order:

```
var result = list.Select(item => new {
    RowType = item.RowType,
    RowValue = list.Where(prior => prior.RowNumber <= item.RowNumber && prior.RowType == item.RowType).Sum(prior => prior.RowValue)
});
```

You can go through `list` once if are willing to sort. (If you know the order is correct, or can use a simpler sort, you can remove or replace the `OrderBy`/`ThenBy`.)

```
var ans = list.OrderBy(x => x.RowType)
              .ThenBy(x => x.RowNumber)
              .Scan(first => new { first.RowType, first.RowValue },
                    (res, cur) => res.RowType == cur.RowType ? new { res.RowType, RowValue = res.RowValue + cur.RowValue }
                                                             : new { cur.RowType, cur.RowValue }
              );
```

This answer uses an extension method that is like `Aggregate`, but returns the intermediate results, based on the APL scan operator:

```
// TRes seedFn(T FirstValue)
// TRes combineFn(TRes PrevResult, T CurValue)
public static IEnumerable<TRes> Scan<T, TRes>(this IEnumerable<T> src, Func<T, TRes> seedFn, Func<TRes, T, TRes> combineFn) {
    using (var srce = src.GetEnumerator()) {
        if (srce.MoveNext()) {
            var prev = seedFn(srce.Current);

            while (srce.MoveNext()) {
                yield return prev;
                prev = combineFn(prev, srce.Current);
            }
            yield return prev;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome help, thank you. I will attempt to incorporate your extension methods after I try to understand all the other nuances you have pointed out above, many thanks!

Comment: @RossBush Not sure of the etiquette, but I replaced my answer with one that uses a better extension method (that I already had lying around!) which I couldn't see how to apply at first, but turns out to work very well.

Comment: If I am reading it correctly, the list is ordered and the scan will seek only to the end of the first group and then the pointer will move to the start of the next group, or where the scan left of last, based on the res comparison result. Whereas, my original attempt would scan the entirety of an unordered list in an attempt to satisfy the where clause, furthermore, it would do that for each item in the list :(

Comment: @RossBush I would phrase it as the scan goes linearly through the ordered list, with a running sum of the `RowValue`, resetting the running sum when `RowType` changes. `Scan` is useful for all kinds of running computations, where `Aggregate` is useful for totalling.

Comment: Ah, ok I can now visualize what the function(s) are doing. Thanks for your help on this.

Answer (score 0):

My eyes were glazed over after seeing this. The answer to my long winded question after 6 hours of skulldrugery seems to be as simple as this. Thanks to @NetMage for pointing out the SelectMany that I was missing.

```
var result = list.SelectMany(item => list.Where(x => x.RowNumber <= item.RowNumber && x.RowType == item.RowType)
.GroupBy(g => g.RowType)
.Select(p => new
{
    RowType = p.Max(s => s.RowType),
    RowValue = p.Sum(s => s.RowValue)
}));
```

Comment: Why `Max` of `RowType` - since you have grouped, they are all the same - you should be able to use `RowType = p.Key`.

Comment: I got it to work and that is the first part. Now I can attempt to determine efficiency as you point out is a problem in your answer that I will  accept above. Thanks!